# How to identify which rows are different in two mysql tables

Tags: mysql, linux

i have  two similar mysql  tables in SQL, i want to identify which rows are different.Can someone help me out with ideas?..Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you have Primary key for each record or unique key for each records and others fields may be different. So you can check which records are not identical.

`select A.<Primary_key/Unique_key>,
        A.<rest of the columns>, 
        B.<rest_of the columns> 
    from Table A , Table B
    where A.<primary_key/Unique_key)>=B.<Primary_key/unique_key>
    and concat(A.field2,'|',A.field3,'|',A.field4) <>
    concat(B.field2,'|',B.field3,'|',B.field4)`;

It is easy to concat and compare all the fields at the same time or you can compare each field separately as follows:

`select A.<Primary_key/Unique_key>, 
        A.Field2,A.Field3,A.Field4, 
        B.Field2,B.Field3,B.Field4 
    from Table A , Table B
    where A.<primary_key/Unique_key)>=B.<Primary_key/unique_key>
    and ( A.Field2 <> B.Field2 OR
      A.Field3 <> B.Field3 OR
      A.Field4 <> B.Field4 );`

I hope this will help.

This is the tool : https://www.red-gate.com/products/mysql/mysql-data-compare/index -- This will compare objects and data.

Another one : https://github.com/DBDiff/DBDiff

Comment: It there any diffing tool out there that will make the  work easier? because i don't have primary key/unique for each record.Thanks